# Use of layout tools attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, layout, android-recyclerview

Is there any possible reason for layout tools attribute to not work in Android Studio 3.1.2?It does show tools, but listitem, text etc are not found!

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:text="Test Text"

        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Please see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCeZy.jpg) for the error.

Comment: You might have already done this, Gradle sync may work sometimes?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit

Comment: tools:text, tools:listitem etc gives me error and doesnt show up in Basic code completion( ctrl + space)

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `tools:text` in the `RecyclerView` element should be fixed.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_checked"
        tools:itemCount="3" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies, that was a mistake while formatting. What do you mean tools:text is broken I was refererring [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-tools-attributes-listitem-sample-data-rocks-bbf49aaa9f07) to learn.

Comment: Yes, broken...saying that there is no '=' sign followed by a (blue) quoted string value, in the line beginning with  'tools:text'

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolsitemcount), you can use `tools:itemCount` for `RecyclerView`.

Comment: You can use `tools:text` for `TextView`.

Comment: @Dave Yes, `="..."` is missing.

Comment: Ehm..I wrote it like it to show that it doesn't show correctly for me. It shows red and as an error, as if listitem doesn't exist or come up in auto complete

Comment: @nandu Apologies, the layout XML in my answer was wrong. `xmlns:tools="...` was missing. I revised it once again, and checked it in Android Studio 3.1.2. It worked for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: No. It's red and treated as error, which is weird. I'll try to post a screenshot when I reach back.